# How to sign .jar file using token (got from softhsm using pkcs11) by jarsigner?

Tags: node.js, pkcs#11, jarsigner, softhsm

I am running softhsm in Windows OS.I am getting token info using pkcs11js npm package.I want to know how i can use the token to sign my .jar file in nodejs?

Token info getting from softhsm using `pkcs11js`

```
'SoftHSM slot ID 0x2d88f571',
manufacturerID: 'SoftHSM project',
  flags: 1,
  hardwareVersion: {
    major: 2,
    minor: 5
  },
  firmwareVersion: {
    major: 2,
    minor: 5
  }
}
token_info-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- - > {
  label: 'My token 2                          ',
  manufacturerID: 'SoftHSM project                 ',
  model: 'SoftHSM v2      ',
  serialNumber: 'ffbf344dad88f571',
  flags: 1069,
  maxSessionCount: 0,
  sessionCount: 4294967295
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - this question needs more detail to be effective. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi the code is just for information regarding token and slot id which is associated with it. :)